# SSH active, but the connection is refused

Tags: raspbian, ssh

I have a Raspberry Pi and I have updated with the latest image.

I have activated SSH and I have verified it is running using the command `service ssh status`.

However, when I connect to it with `putty` in Windows or run `ssh -x < Raspberry Pi IP addr > -l pi`, the connection is refused.

I don't understand what I am missing?

Comment: Have you configured it to require keyed authentication rather than password authentication?

Comment: Ok, if you get a `connection refused` then the daemon is not listening on `port 22` (or isn't running at all). First, do a `ps afxu | grep sshd` and add the output to your question. If the daemon is running, try to run `ssh -vvv <ipaddress>` and paste into your question a few lines of output before `ssh` hangs or refuses the connection. If you have a monitor and keyboard attached to your Pi, you can also try a `ssh -vvv localhost` directly on the Pi to see if at least this works.

Comment: At first, I assume you want `ssh -X` not -x
Second: Doublecheck the raspi's IP address with `ifconfig`
Third: `ssh -vvv` will tell you, if your configuration is not correct, or permissions aren't set properly.

Comment: You could also grep the output of netstat -n for port 22.  And you might want to make sure that what is answering at that IP address is actually the pi, and not something having an address conflict with it - you might for example do arp -an on your development box and look up the first three octets of the MAC address corresponding to that IP - it should match the pi - if it belongs to someone else like Dell or Cisco you know it's not the pi you have been talking to.

Comment: On the client, `ssh -v` would give more detailed error messages.

Comment: I believe this post still needs an answer.
In some cases (in mine for instance), it is not possible to access via ssh, even though the actual noobs version has been used, the right ip address is known, etc.
There must be more things to consider, if you want to start running the PI with putty via SSH, because you don´t have any HDMI device at hand.

Comment: @Thomas The problem *is* that there is more to consider, but the only person who can consider it is the person who is there.  As Avio observes in a comment above, what "connection refused" literally means is [nothing is listening on the port](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/73782/25985).  If `ssh` is supposedly running, we are now left with a mystery that could have many answers and thus requires further investigation...but the O.P. did not even respond to any of the above comments...

Comment: ...Also note this is *not* a discussion forum; it's a Q&A site (if you have not taken [the tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) yet, please do).  What that means is there a certain minimum level of effort you have to be able to make in diagnosing your own problem so that you can provide relevant information to make the problem specific enough to have *an* answer.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have the wrong IP address. To show the IP, type this command on the Pi:

```
ip -s addr
```

The, there should be an IP address beginning with `192.168` or look for the "inet" address associated with your eth(typically 0) interface. Try the SSH command again with that IP address.